# 2D array working inside the loop but not working outside the loop

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have coded a formula to read the txt file, store it in array(1D) and then reading the array to calculate the moving average(2D). Program ask the user to input two values (`k1` & `k2`) and calculate the moving average for every value from `k1` to `k2` (basically to find out the best value)
Following is the code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int count = 0,k1=0,k2=0,k=0; // Line counter (result)
  int buy[k2][count],sell[k2][count];

  char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
  char c; // To store a character read from file

  // Get file name from user. The file should be
  // either in current folder or complete path should be provided
  printf("Enter file name or full path: ");
  scanf("%s", filename);
  printf("Enter the minimum rolling period for calculation : \n");
  scanf("%d", &k1);
  printf("Enter the maximum rolling period for calculation : \n");
  scanf("%d", &k2);
  // Open the file

  fp = fopen(filename, "r");

  // Check if file exists
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  // Extract characters from file and store in character c
  for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
      count = count + 1;

  // Close the file
  fclose(fp);
  //printf("The file %s has %d lines\n", filename, count);

  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

  //read file into array
  float numberArray[count];
  int i;

  if (myFile == NULL){
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i]);
  }

  fclose(myFile);

  for (k=k1;k<=k2;k++)
  {
    float n;
    float data[count],mag[k2][count];
    double avg,sum;
    for (i=0;i<k-1;i++)
    {
      mag[k][i-1]=0;
      sum=sum+numberArray[i];
    }

    for(i=k-1;i<=count;i++)
    {
      mag[k][i-1]=avg;
      sum=sum+numberArray[i]-numberArray[i-k];
      avg = sum/k;
    }

    //    for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
    //    {
    //        printf("MA[%d][%d] = %0.2lf     ",k,i,mag[k][i]);
    //        if (i%3==0)
    //            printf("\n");
    //    }
  }

  for(k=k1;k<=k2;k++)
  {
    for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
      printf("MA[%d][%d] = %0.2lf     ",k,i,mag[k][i]);
  }
}
}
```

Now when I am trying to print `mag[k][i]` values outside the for loop, it is showing error 'mag' undeclared. But when I am putting the print command inside the loop (comment out portion in the code), it works fine.

UPDATED CODE AFTER FOLLOWING COMMENTS (STILL NOT WORKING THOUGH)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#define MAXCHAR 1000

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int count,k1,k2,k; // Line counter (result)
  char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME];
  char c; // To store a character read from file

  // Get file name from user. The file should be
  // either in current folder or complete path should be provided
  printf("Enter file name or full path: ");
  scanf("%s", filename);

  printf("Enter the minimum rolling period for calculation : \n");
  scanf("%d", &k1);

  printf("Enter the maximum rolling period for calculation : \n");
  scanf("%d", &k2);

  // Open the file
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  // Check if file exists
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Could not open file %s", filename);
    return 0;
  }

  // Extract characters from file and store in character c
  for (c = getc(fp); c != EOF; c = getc(fp))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
      count = count + 1;

  // Close the file
  fclose(fp);
  //printf("The file %s has %d lines\n", filename, count);

  /****************
    File opening and reading section
   *****************************************************/
  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen(filename, "r");

  //read file into array
  float numberArray[count];
  int i;

  if (myFile == NULL){
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit (0);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    fscanf(myFile, "%f,", &numberArray[i] );
  }
  fclose(myFile);

  /***********************************************
   Calculation of Moving Average and storing it in array
   ******************************************/
  int buy[k2][count],sell[k2][count];
  float mag[k2][count];
  for (k=k1;k<=k2;k++)
  {
    float data[count];
    double avg,sum;
    for (i=1;i<k;i++)
    {
      mag[k][i-1]=0;
      sum=sum+numberArray[i];
    }

    for (i=k-1;i<=count;i++)
    {
      mag[k][i-1]=avg;
      sum=sum+numberArray[i]-numberArray[i-k];
      avg = sum/k;
    }

//    for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
//    {
//        printf("MA[%d][%d] = %0.2lf     ",k,i,mag[k][i]);
//        if (i%3==0)
//            printf("\n");
//    }
   }

   for (k=k1;k<=k2;k++)
   {
     for (i=0;i<=count;i++)
     {
       printf("MA[%d][%d] = %0.2lf     ",k,i,mag[k][i]);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve the readability of your code a lot by indenting it properly. This will attract more readers.

Comment: You can’t use `count` as an array dimension like that.

Comment: i have just edited/indented the code to make it more readable.. thanks @Gerhardh

Comment: Well, actually I edited it and you changed it back to some version with strange indentation. I'll revert back

Comment: `int buy[k2][count],sell[k2][count];` At this line `count` contains 0. That is probably not what you want.

Comment: You need to read a bit about scope of variables. Whatever you define within a block enclosed by `{ }` is not visible outside.

Comment: As gerhardh said, you declare mag inside the for loop, so outside the loop it won't exist, and you're using VLA, take a look of what is it

Comment: @Gerhardh , thank you for correcting me.. as i am new to C, thus i did that mistake.. but even after correcting it.. its compiling and not showing error, but results of all values of mag[][] are zero now :-(

Comment: You might update your question to show the new code. Use the "edit" button and add the modified code below your old code. Removing the old code is not encouraged as it would make all comments and answers useless.

Comment: `mag[k][i-1]=0;` In that loop `k` runs up to `<=k2` which is 1 too much and `i` starts at 0, making `i-1` a bit too low.

Comment: I have added the updated code after following comments... but still its not working :-(

Comment: `char c` needs to be `int c` otherwise you may not be able to detect EOF correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem boils down to this: the scope of `mag` is limited to the inside of the `for` loop:

```
  for (k = k1; k <= k2; k++)
  {
    ...
    int mag[k2][count];
    ... 
  }

  // mag is out of scope here
  // therefore following line won't compile:

  printf("%d", mag[0][0]);
```

You need to declare `mag` outside the for loop for example like this:

```
  int mag[k2][count];      
  for (k = k1; k <= k2; k++)
  {
    ...
  }

  printf("%d", mag[0][0]);
  ...
```

Beware: there are other problems within your code, mentioned in the comments.

Comment: If i am putting it outside the loop then it is not showing error in compilation, but when run it is showing error : The instruction at referenced memory could not be read. Click OK to terminate the program.

Comment: @MohdNaved this is because of other unrelated errors in your code. Read  Gerhardh's second comment.

Comment: ohh yes, my mistake.. i just corrected as per the guidelines of Gerhardh.. now its working but a new issue arises now.. its showing all values of mag[][] equal to zero :-(

Comment: @MohdNaved that's a very different question. It's a perfect opportunity to learn how to use the debugger. It's a small invesment in time, which will pay off very quickly.

Comment: code was working fine when user was supposed to enter only one value of k, and mag was one dimensional.. but when i modified the code to let user enter two values k1 & k2.. and converted moving average into 2D, since then i am in trouble.